# Find a solution bounded near $x=0$ of the following ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

Fine a solution bounded near $x=0$ of the following ODE
 $$x^2y''+xy'+( \lambda ^2x^2-1)y=0$$

my attempt :

this is Bessel's equation so let $u=\lambda x$ then $y(x)=y(\frac{u}{\lambda})$

Also $y'(x)=\lambda Y'(u)$ and $y''(x)=\lambda^2Y''(u)$

then the give equation reduced to $u^2Y''(u)+uY'(u)+(\lambda^2-1)Y(u)=0$

then the general solution is $Y(u)=AJ_1(u)+BY_1(u)=AJ_1(\lambda x)+BY_1(\lambda x)=y(x)$

**But what a solution  bounded near $x=0$ ?**

Comment: You should choose $B=0$.

Comment: @Jon..how we can choose B=0

Comment: $A$ and $B$ are arbitrary constant. If you are asked for a solution bounded in 0, $J_1$ is and $Y_1$ is not. So, you have to fix $B=0$.

Comment: $y\equiv 0$ is a bounded solution ;)

Comment: @MPW The trivial one! :)